# Friendly_ID url inside a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I am using Rails with React in my app, and I wanted to pass url for `Post` model in `as_json` method. It has been working correctly with this method found on SO, where I pass the `locale` and the `id` (or `self.id`):

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.post_path(locale, id)
```

I have now included `FriendlyID` gem in my project and I can go to my post page using the generated `slug`, but the method above still returns the old URL with ID. My question is - how can I change that?

PS I can do just (code below), but was wondering if there is an easier way?

```
...posts_path(locale) + "/#{slug}"
```

Comment: Use [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) or jbuilder instead of monkeying around with the `.to_json` method. I would argue that models should not be aware of the current locale or anything request related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way (and the way `Rails` was designed to do it) is

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.post_path(locale, to_param)
```

the `to_param` method by default returns the `:id` as a string but is overridden by people who use slugs directly  or via gems like friendlyID

Comment: Wow, great! Thank you so much, sir!